# Angularjs with Bootstrap-Datepicker: input not actively being recognized

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to create an AngularJS application using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datepicker.date" class="span4">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
{{ datepicker.date }}
```

The last line is for debugging purposes. When this page is in action, the datepicker works fine and writes any date I pick into the `input` box. The issue is, as I click on a date, the `{{ datepicker.date }}` part does not show anything until I manually type something into the `input` box. I would like it to actively show any date I pick.

Here is an image trying to explain what's happening:

[image]

If possible, I would also like to type in my own input into the input box. Any selected dates would simply be added into the input box.

Answer (score 1):

See **[AngularJS and `scope.$apply`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)** and the [answer to this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397361/binding-the-model-value-of-twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-in-controller-in-angular).

Your `<input>` is bound to `datepicker.date`, so when you update it directly by adding the 'x', `{{datepicker.date}}` is updated. When you close the datepicker, no changes are made to the `<input>` so AngularJS doesn't know to re-evaluate the expression. You need to call `scope.$apply` explicitly when the datepicker is closed.